How do you learn Blender on a Chromebook
I'm new to 3d modeling and I want to learn Blender.
I'm on a Chromebook, so I don't know if that has anything to do with my trouble.

This is an incredibly vague question; however, I'll throw some good resources below.

I think if you are serious about it, you should consider getting a Windows PC with a big 4K screen and good Nvidia GPU and full size standard keyboard and good mouse for learning Blender. It's not a requirement. Yes, Blender will work on many different kinds of hardware and OSes and yes, you could possibly use a Chromebook, but just because you could, doesn't mean you should. Chromebook is not a very smart choice for this. It's designed for other purpose. Learning 3d is very hard on its own. Why make your life even harder?..

@MartynasŽiemys Although a 4K monitor is overkill, you could use several of them, I use a single 27" Full HD one.

It's not overkill. 4K monitor makes a huge difference. Its not only me I am talking about. I have observed it in others. I have seen in work environment after switching from HD to 4K people report it's a lot easier to work and that it's a huge deal and big improvement. I have had friends freaking out about what a good advice it was to go for a big 4K monitor as well. It makes huge difference in terms of convenience. It's a solid tested advice. Go for a big 4K monitor if possible.

I have personally used Blender on a Chromebook, and it's a bit difficult.  They don't have perfect support, and rendering power is non-existent.However, if you're just looking to learn how to model, it will probably be fine, if you keep it basic.
To install Blender on a Chromebook, you must enable the developer enviroment.
Then, download Blender.  Extract it into your Linux Files.  You will likely have to do this in the terminal.  Open the terminal, and type tar -xf and then the name of the file you downloaded from Blender.org.
To run Blender, open the terminal, and type blender-4.1.1-linux-x64/blender, replacing everything before the "/" with the name of the folder you extracted earlier.
Now that you have Blender working, I highly recomend going through the Donut Tutorial.  It is well made, clear, beginner friendly, and comprehensive.  It'll be tough, stick with it!

Thanks. IMO, this is a really useful answer for folks with limited resources, and so makes the question useful, too.

Chromebook may cost around 300 euros. It might also be a waste of money for someone who is interested in 3d as that could be spent more effectively for that interest.

@RobinBetts Awesome, that was exactly what I was going for.  I don't ever want to kill someone's love of learning, so it was my hope that would be enough to get him started.

@MartynasŽiemys For sure, it's  not the best spend for the purpose. But if it's what you have, it's what you have. And there's an awful lot of learning that can be done before the poor thing grinds to a halt :)  And not just that.. sometimes the greatest art comes from the tightest constraints. It's amazing what some people come up with, when they're cornered.

Sure. If that's all you have - that's amazing, it's infinitely better than no computer and that's all great. Still I think it's very important to keep in mind that it's not ideal and it's possible to increase your chances of success in learning. Robin Betts, do you know anybody who started learning 3d and after a while just forgot about it?.. I've seen a few situations like this. If it's harder to do everything just a little bit, I think it might play a role in this. But then again, there are probably people, who don't give up no matter the circumstances.
